# What is a work around for the fact that setting BitArray.Length to a lower value doesn't always change internal "m_array"?

Tags: c#, binary, converters

To clarify: System.Collections.BitArray

When I say "doesn't always" I'm not saying it is random or seemingly random, it seems consistent that when the length is reduced such that the new length is within a lower multiple of "some number" (not known by me, possibly 8) then the internal "m_array" shrinks as expected.

I am making something that requires data of arbitrary numbers of bits, anything from 0-65535, and I need to be able to turn unsigned, signed, double, float, and strings into BitArrays and back. Libraries are also out of the question for various reasons.

I need a work around since the (extremely) unexpected behaviour of BitArray.Length is lacking.

Here is an example of when it wouldn't work:

```
    private const int _lengthInBits = 3; //not actually a const in program

    private BitArray BitArrayFromLong(long lng)
    {
        return new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(lng)) { Length = _lengthInBits };
    }

    private long BitArrayToLong(BitArray bitArray)
    {
        bitArray.Length = _lengthInBits; //this shouldn't be required but didn't think it would hurt
        var byteArray = new byte[sizeof(long)];
        bitArray.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray, 0);
    }
```

So when I call `BitArrayToLong(BitArrayFromLong(15))` I SHOULD get 7, because 15 is converted to true, true, true, true, true (11111), which then SHOULD be turned into true, true, true (111), which it is, but the internal value of 15 is still stored in this "m_array", which seems to determine the copied value in the byteArray in the second method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I came up with was two methods:

```
    private static void SetBitArrayLength(ref BitArray bitArray, ushort newLength)
    {
        bitArray.Length = newLength;
        RepairBitArray(ref bitArray);
    }

    private static void RepairBitArray(ref BitArray bitArray)
    {
        var returnBitArray = new BitArray(bitArray.Length);
        for (var index = 0; index < bitArray.Length; index++)
        {
            returnBitArray[index] = bitArray[index];
        }
        bitArray = returnBitArray;
    }
```

Replace the length assignment with SetBitArrayLength and it works as originally expected, 7 is returned when calling `BitArrayToLong(BitArrayFromLong(15))`